# Preserving the WCS information of a FITS file when rebinned

Tags: python, astropy, fits

**Aim** : Rebin an existing image (FITS file) and write the new entries into a new rebinned image (also a FITS file).

**Issue** : Rebinned FITS file and the original FITS file seem to have mismatched co-ordinates (figure shown later in the question).

**Process** : I will briefly describe my process to shed more light. The first step is to read the existing fits file and define numpy arrays

```
from math import *
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
from astropy.visualization import astropy_mpl_style
from astropy.io import fits 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib notebook
import aplpy
from aplpy import FITSFigure



file = 'F0621_HA_POL_0700471_HAWDHWPD_PMP_070-199Augy20.fits'
hawc = fits.open(file)

stokes_i = np.array(hawc[0].data)
stokes_i_rebinned = congrid(stokes_i,newdim,method="neighbour", centre=False, minusone=False)
```

Here "congrid" is a function I have used for near-neigbhour rebinning that rebins the original array to a new dimension given by "newdim". Now the goal is to write this rebinned array back into the FITS file format as a new file. I have several more such arrays but for brevity, I just include one array as an example. To keep the header information same, I read the header information of that array from the existing FITS file and use that to write the new array into a new FITS file. After writing, the rebinned file can be read just like the original :-

```
header_0= hawc[0].header
fits.writeto("CasA_HAWC+_rebinned_congrid.fits", rebinned_stokes_i, header_0, overwrite=True)

rebinned_file = 'CasA_HAWC+_rebinned_congrid.fits'
hawc_rebinned= fits.open(rebinned_file)
```

To check how the rebinned image looks now I plot them

```
cmap = 'rainbow'

stokes_i = hawc[0]
stokes_i_rebinned = hawc_rebinned[0]

axi = FITSFigure(stokes_i, subplot=(1,2,1))  # generate FITSFigure as subplot to have two axes together
axi.show_colorscale(cmap=cmap)              # show I


axi_rebinned = FITSFigure(stokes_i_rebinned, subplot=(1,2,2),figure=plt.gcf())
axi_rebinned.show_colorscale(cmap=cmap)              # show I rebinned

# FORMATTING
axi.set_title('Stokes I (146 x 146)')
axi_rebinned.set_title('Rebinned Stokes I (50 x 50)')
axi_rebinned.axis_labels.set_yposition('right')
axi_rebinned.tick_labels.set_yposition('right')
axi.tick_labels.set_font(size='small')
axi.axis_labels.set_font(size='small')
axi_rebinned.tick_labels.set_font(size='small')
axi_rebinned.axis_labels.set_font(size='small')
```

[image]

As you see for the original and rebinned image, the X,Y co-ordinates seem mismatched and my best guess was that WCS (world co-ordinate system) for the original FITS file wasn't properly copied for the new FITS file, thus causing any mismatch. So how do I align these co-ordinates ?

Any help will be deeply appreciated ! Thanks

Comment: Is `stokes_i_rebinned` the same as `stokes_i_rebinned`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @astrochun already said, your re-binning function does not adjust the WCS of the re-binned image. In addition to `reproject` and `Montage`, `astropy.wcs.WCS`object  has `slice()` method. You could try using it to "re-bin" the WCS like this:

```
from astropy.wcs import WCS
import numpy as np
wcs = WCS(hawc[0].header, hawc)
wcs_rebinned = wcs.slice((np.s_[::2], np.s_[::2]))
wcs_hdr = wcs_rebinned.to_header()
header_0.update(wcs_hdr)  # but watch out for CD->PC conversion
```

You should also make a "real" copy of `hawc[0].header` in `header_0= hawc[0].header`, for example as `header_0= hawc[0].header.copy()` or else `header_0.update(wcs_hdr)` will modify `hawc[0].header` as well.

Comment: @Astronomer The following function may help with PC->CD conversion if you need it: https://github.com/spacetelescope/stwcs/blob/47f9ca11e275a1ecb15f1696f6a52c16d24d2431/stwcs/wcsutil/altwcs.py#L1067-L1093 You can then simply call `pc2cd(header_0)` to get back to `CD` matrix representation.

Answer (score 2):

I'm posting my answer in an astropy slack channel here should this be useful for others.

`congrid` will not work because it doesn't include information about the WCS. For example, your CD matrix is tied to the original image, not the re-binned set. There are a number of way to re-bin data with proper WCS.  You might consider [reproject](https://reproject.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) although this often requires another WCS header to re-bin to.

[Montage](http://montage.ipac.caltech.edu/) (though not a Python tool but has Python wrappers) is potentially another way.

Comment: Thank you. I used wcs.slice to add the information about wcs. Now the images seem aligned !